# Different iw list for the same USB Wifi device on Raspberry pi and ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I have a TP-Link WN721N USB Wifi adapter.
I plan to setup two virtual interfaces, one for station and one for AP, on my rpi.

The problem is `iw list` on rpi shows my adapter does not support interface combinations and I am unable to setup two interfaces at the same time, but when I plug in the same adapter into my ubuntu machine and run `iw list` it shows that it supports interface combinations and I can actually create the interfaces.

What am I missing here? How can I fix this, any ideas?

Output on **Ubuntu**:

```
$ iw list
Wiphy phy3
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x116e
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0x1 RX 0x1
    Configured Antennas: TX 0x1 RX 0x1
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed, P2P-client } <= 2, #{ AP, mesh point, P2P-GO } <= 2,
           total <= 2, #channels <= 1
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * new_beacon
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_params
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * action
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * Unknown command (84)
         * Unknown command (87)
         * Unknown command (85)
         * Unknown command (89)
         * Unknown command (92)
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * Unknown mode (10): 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * Unknown mode (10): 0x40 0xd0
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.`
```

Output on Raspberry Pi running **Raspbian**:

```
pi@myraspi-01 ~ $ iw list
Wiphy phy0
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x116e
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT20 SGI
            RX HT40 SGI
            RX STBC 1-stream
            Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    max scan IEs length: 2257 bytes
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP (00-0f-ac:4)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    interface combinations are not supported
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * new_beacon
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_params
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * action
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * set_wds_peer
         * Unknown command (84)
         * Unknown command (87)
         * Unknown command (85)
         * connect
         * disconnect
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
    Device supports RSN-IBSS.
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are using two different kernel versions on the two machines. They contain different versions of the driver, which has different capabilities.

You can check kernel version with

> ```
> uname -a
> ```

Comment: You were right, I updated the raspberry pi firmware with rpi-update and now the driver and iw seem to be working fine.